# How to check the radio button is clicked after submit the page

Tags: php, sql

**question**

```
**question_id  question  option1 option2 option3 option4   answer** 
15          AAA         a1     a2      a3       a4           3
38          BBB         b1     b2      b3       b             2
39          CCC         c1     c2      c3       c4            4
44          DDD         d1     d2      d3       d4            2
45          EEE         e1     e2      e3       e4            1
```

**start_exam.php**

```
$query="select * from exam_question_list where exam_paper_id='$exam_paper_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$que1=$row['q1'];

<form action="exam_paper_result.php?1=<?php echo $row['q1'];?>>
<?php 
    $sql1="SELECT question_id AS qid, question AS q, option1 AS op1, option2 AS op2, option3 AS op3, option4 AS op4 FROM question where question_id='$que1'";


        $data1=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql1);

    while($datan1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)){

        $i=0;
?>
  <tr>
     <tr data-label="Question"><td><span>(01)&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><?php echo $datan1['q'];  ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a1" value="1"/><?php echo $datan1['op1']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a1" value="2"/><?php echo $datan1['op2']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a1" value="3"/><?php echo $datan1['op3']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input type="radio"  name="a1" value="4"/><?php echo $datan1['op4']; ?></td></tr>  

    </tr>


<?php
    }
    ?>

 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**exam_paper_result.php**

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {


$qu1 =$_GET['1'];
$q1 =  $_POST['a1'];

$score ="";

$sql1="SELECT question_id AS qid, answer AS a FROM question where question_id='$qu1'";
$result1=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql1);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

if (!isset($q1)) {
 echo("Error: please specify a type, new or old");
 //$score = 0;

 } else {

if($row1['a'] == $q1){
    echo "correct";
    //$score = 1;

}else{
    echo "wrong";
    //$score = 1;
}   
}

 }
  ?>
```

When I select correct option then print 'correct'
When I select wrong option then print 'wrong'
When I not select any option and click submit ; there is an error

"Notice: Undefined index: a1 in G:\xampp\htdocs\examination_system\src\applicant\exam_paper_result.php on line 38
Error:NOT select any answer"

Comment: can you explain more clear

Comment: there is a question and 4 options in "start_exam.php" , I want to set the score for the question, when I not select the any option and click submit, I want to print 'empty' in "result.php"

Comment: add required in input I think that will fix everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When no radio button is checked, it's possibly showing that notice in this line:

```
$q1 =  $_POST['a1'];
```

Change it to this:

```
 $q1 =  isset($_POST['a1']) ? $_POST['a1'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. so you need to use isset function.

```
 $q1 = null;    
 if(isset($_POST['a1'])){
 $q1 = $_POST['a1'];
}
```

you can also use this conditio

```
$q1 = isset($_POST['a1']) ? $_POST['a1'] : null;
```

and you any radio type required like this then you can not submit this form without check any radio

```
<form>
<label for="input1">Label 1:</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="input1" value="1" required>     <br>

<label for="input2">Label 2:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="input2" value="2"><br>

<label for="input3">Label 3:</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="input3" value="3"><br>

<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

for more information you can check this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php